# Is it possible to draw a graph with a Hamilton Path but not a Euler Cycle?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Is it possible to draw a graph with a Hamilton Path but not a Euler Cycle?

It seems that every graph I draw has a Hamilton Path.

Comment: But what's wrong with that?  You're looking for graphs that have Hamiltonian paths .. (or am I missing something?)

Comment: sorry I'll edit

Comment: A path itself would do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Consider the graph that consists of a single octagon (a cycle of length 8), then add any two vertex-disjoint diagonals. Then it certainly has a Hamiltonian path (just take the Hamiltonian cycle formed by the octagon and delete an edge), yet it has no Eulerian circuit. In fact, it doesn't even have an Eulerian trail, since adding the two diagonal edges resulted in a graph with four vertices of odd degree (these four vertices now have degree three).